# How does apt/dpkg choose which real package is installed when a virtual package is specified as a dependency?

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

e.g. if  package specifies

```
Depends: www-browser
```

How does apt/dpkg decide which real package will be installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/739065/457562) on Ask Ubuntu, apt will first try to install any non-virtual packages listed as options instead:

> Now, according to sources, apt tries first of [satisfying the dependency before](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/depcache.cc#L1542) trying with [virtual packages](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/depcache.cc#L1956) (i.e., if depends are `firefox | www-browser`, checks if any of the packages are installed, then try to install firefox if neither is).

If not, it will simply iterate over the list of packages that provide the virtual one, and install the first one that it can:

> If the non-virtual package isn't available, it seems to just iterate over [all packages which provides the virtual package](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/depcache.cc#L372), if no other dependencies are broken. Other comments evidence of this behavior are [this](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/cacheiterators.h#L122) which leads to [GrpIterator::FindPreferredPkg function](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/9de2fd4d117e57824f4a0795efa7379995a804cb/apt-pkg/pkgcache.cc#L403).

Comment: It is discouraged to use pure virtual dependencies, usually you'd give one real and one virtual package as in your example. For `Build-Depends`, this is required by policy as well, as "or" relationships are ignored by autobuilders.

Comment: @SimonRichter Yes, it makes sense to discourage purely virtual dependencies because apt will just install any package that provides it, which is rarely what you'd want.